# Images in listview with smooth scrolling

Tags: android

Currently I am not having server to upload the images and the images will be twice time if i copy images assets to sdcard, so I put all images in assets folder.The size of images are large, it takes time to decode and scale images. 
I want to use lazy loading to show theses images.But I can use lazy loading code only when images are coming from  sdcard or web server.

Please suggest me how can i show images from assets folder with smooth scrolling.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> But I can use lazy loading code only when images are coming from
>   sdcard or web server

You can use lazy loading with any source. Are you using an existing implementation, or did you create your own? If you have the code, you can easily extend it so that it allows loading images from assets.